# I wanna make input text field required using javascript ,but currently its not working as expected,though it works as expected for checkbox field

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am not able to detect what I am doing wrong in this piece of code

```
<apex:page >
<apex:form id="myForm">
    <apex:pageblock id="pb1">
        <apex:pageblockSection id="pbs1">
            <apex:inputText id="Name" label="Enter Name" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox1" label="Check Me" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Click Me !" onclick="getCheckBoxValue();"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
<script language="javascript">
    function getCheckBoxValue()
    {

       if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb1.pbs1.Name}').value == '')
        {
            alert('Name is mandatory');
        }

       else
       {
           alert('You have entered the Name');
       }
    }
</script>
```

The below code is working fine:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:form id="myForm">
    <apex:pageblock id="pb1">
        <apex:pageblockSection id="pbs1">
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox1" label="Check Me" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Click Me !" onclick="getCheckBoxValue();"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
<script language="javascript">
    function getCheckBoxValue()
    {
       var status = (document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb1.pbs1.checkbox1}').checked);
       if(status==true)
       {
           alert('You have checked it.');
       }
       else
       {
           alert('Check it first.');
       }
    }
</script>
```

[image: Alerts Coming for Checkbox field]

[image: Alerts Coming for Checkbox field]

Comment: alerts coming or not?

Comment: Alerts are not coming when I am using it for Input Text Field,though they are coming for Check box field

Comment: actually you do not need any alert or anything extra as you already added "required". whenever u submit form will automatically alert you for that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve it by `required` attribute alone in `inputText` instead of using Javascript. You have to include:

`<apex:pageMessages/>`

in you VF page to show any errors.

[image: Error:]

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:pageblock id="pb1">
            <apex:pageblockSection id="pbs1">
                    <apex:inputText id="Name" label="Enter Name" required="true"/>

                <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox1" label="Check Me" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Click Me !" onclick="getCheckBoxValue();"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    function getCheckBoxValue()
    {
        console.log('Getting Val. ');
        if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb1.pbs1.Name}').value == '')
        {
            alert('Name is mandatory');
        }

        else
        {
            alert('You have entered the Name');
        }
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I just dont know  when I did this  , why the alerts for checkboxes stopped to come?

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena The above code is working fine for me. Please check for any JavaScript errors in browsers console.

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:page >
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:form id="myForm">
    <apex:pageblock id="pb1">
        <apex:pageblockSection id="pbs1">
            <apex:inputText id="Name" label="Enter Name" />
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox1" label="Check Me" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Click Me !" onclick="getCheckBoxValue();" rendered="true"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
<script language="javascript">
function getCheckBoxValue()

{
    //console.log('Getting Val. ');

   var status = (document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb1.pbs1.checkbox1}').checked);
   var name=(document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb1.pbs1.Name}').value);
   if((name == '') && (status==false) )
    {

                alert('Enter Name First');
                alert('Check it');

    }



    else 
    if(( name == '') && (status==true) )
    {
                alert('Enter Name First');

                alert('Checked');

    }

    else 
    if(( name != '') && (status==true) )
    {

                alert('Name Entered');
                alert('Checked');

    }
     else 
    if(( name != '') && (status==false) )
    {

                alert('Name Entered');
                alert('Check it');

    }

         }

</script>
```